# How can we enable Amazon S3 replication modification sync in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, replication

I am working on an Amazon S3 replication using terraform . I want to enable rule "Repilcate modification sync" but I don't think so it is defined in terraform .

Right now my code looks :

```
replication_configuration {
    role = "${aws_iam_role.source_replication.arn}"

    rules {
      id     = "${local.replication_name}"
      status = "Enabled"
      prefix = "${var.replicate_prefix}"

      destination {
        bucket        = "${local.dest_bucket_arn}"
        storage_class = "STANDARD"

        access_control_translation = {
          owner = "Destination"
        }

        account_id = "${data.aws_caller_identity.dest.account_id}"
      }

      source_selection_criteria {
        replica_modifications {
          Status = "Enabled"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

It gives an error :

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on s3_bucket.tf line 61, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket":
  61:         replica_modifications {

Blocks of type "replica_modifications" are not expected here.
```

The rules which I have to enable looks like this in console.
[image]

With AWS CLI in terraform , I am not sure how can I use variables like destination `${local.dest_bucket_arn}` and `${aws_iam_role.source_replication.arn}` in my son file which I am calling.

```
resource "null_resource" "awsrepl" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3api put-bucket-replication --replication-configuration templatefile://replication_source.json --bucket ${var.bucket_name}"
    
  }
}
```

replication_source.json looks like :

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "DeleteMarkerReplication": { "Status": "Enabled" },
            "SourceSelectionCriteria": {
                "ReplicaModifications":{
                    "Status": "Enabled"
                }
            },
            "Destination": {
                "Bucket": "${local.dest_bucket_arn}"
            },
            "Priority": 1
        }
    ],
    "Role": "${aws_iam_role.source_replication.arn}"
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't enable this from terraform directly?

Comment: I am unsure of how I can use was aws cli variables in terraform . Check question for updated code in terraform using aws cli .

Comment: @Marcin do check the comment above. and let me know if you have some ideas

Comment: I would suggest to make new question specifically about using local-exec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. It is **not yet supported**, but there is a GitHub issue for that already:

- [Amazon S3 Two-way Replication via Replica Modification Sync](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/16539)

By the way, `Delete marker replication` is also not supported.

Your options are to either do it manually after you deploy your bucket, or use [local-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html) to run AWS CLI to do it, or [aws_lambda_invocation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_invocation).

Answer (score 1):

Was able to achieve this using local-exec and temmplate_file in terraform :

```
data "template_file" "replication_dest" {
  template = "${file("replication_dest.json")}"
  vars = {
    srcarn = "${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn}"
    destrolearn = "${aws_iam_role.dest_replication.arn}"
    kmskey = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}"
    keyalias = "${data.aws_kms_key.s3.key_id}"
    srcregion = "${data.aws_region.active.name}"
  }
}
```

```
resource "null_resource" "awsdestrepl" {
  # ...
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws s3api put-bucket-replication --bucket ${aws_s3_bucket.dest.bucket} --replication-configuration ${data.template_file.replication_dest.rendered}"
    
  }
  depends_on = [aws_s3_bucket.dest]
}
```

And `replication_dest.json` looks like this :

```
"{
    \"Rules\": [
        {
            \"Status\": \"Enabled\",
            \"DeleteMarkerReplication\": { \"Status\": \"Enabled\" },
            \"Filter\": {\"Prefix\": \"\"},
            \"SourceSelectionCriteria\": {
                \"ReplicaModifications\":{
                    \"Status\": \"Enabled\"
                },
                \"SseKmsEncryptedObjects\":{
                    \"Status\": \"Enabled\"
                }
            },
            \"Destination\": {
                \"Bucket\": \"${bucketarn}\",
                \"EncryptionConfiguration\": {
                    \"ReplicaKmsKeyID\": \"arn:aws:kms:${destregion}:${kmskey}:${keyalias}\"
                  }
        },
            \"Priority\": 1
        }
    ],
    \"Role\": \"${rolearn}\"
}"
```

And you are good to go . :)